# How does an observer in arbitrary state of motion assign numbers to events in a flat spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, observers

In a flat spacetime, there is an inertial observer, who assigns events coordinates in a usual fashion: Placing a clock everywhere and synchronize them. From his POV, the other observer is moving in the $x$ axis with a constant acceleration $a$. How does one underlie the relation between the coordinates assigned by the two for an arbitrary single event? Or, how does the accelerating observer even assign coordinate for an event?

Comment: The metrics on these spacetimes transform to each other by this formula: $g^{\mu'\nu'}=\frac{\partial x^{\mu'}}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^\nu} g^{\mu\nu}$
where $x^\mu$, $x^{\mu'}$,... are the coordinates on two spacetimes. (primed for one of them and unprimed for the other)

Comment: I'm trying to ask: How does one parametrize the coordinates assigned by the accelerating observer in terms of the coordinates assigned by an inertial observer, so your formula here is irrelavent. By the way ,your formula is wrong, it should be $g_{μ'ν'}=\frac{∂x^μ}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{∂x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}g_{μν}$

Comment: Are you sure you corrected that formula?!! Parametrization is a tricky work and I think can be done in many ways. Do you have a special problem?

Comment: Yes i'm sure with index up, we mean it's the inverse matrix. Any special example should be ok.